# Is it possible to get Windows 7 installed on a laptop with Vista Home Basic?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista

My laptop is Acer EXtensa 5620Z purchased within 2 years with Vista Home Basic installed.
I wish to try out Windows 7.  Are there any expenses involved in the change over please ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

You would not be entitled to a free upgrade but you can buy either an upgrade edition or a fresh OEM copy.

Upgrade will install over the top of your current and may be the simplest way of using it. OEM would be a fresh install.

Neither of witch would really let you "test out Windows 7" though, it would be an actual new Operating system.

I would recommend, if you know about virtualisation, you install [Microsoft Virtual PC 2007](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=04D26402-3199-48A3-AFA2-2DC0B40A73B6&displaylang=en) and a [Windows 7 VHD](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=606ae07e-b7db-405b-974b-dd61fc41add4&displaylang=en). This will let you test Windows 7 from within Windows Vista.

Also, if you have a [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com) or [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com) Subscription, you may be able to get Windows 7 for free.

Comment: No, Benedict can't buy an "OEM" copy (legally), because no such version exists for his computer.  He can buy a *retail* copy.

Before installing, use the Windows 7 Upgrade Advisor (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=1b544e90-7659-4bd9-9e51-2497c146af15&displayLang=en) to be sure your system can run that OS.

Comment: The licence has changed a lot in recent years - the copy is just another commodity and he can buy it as any other good or service as long as it is fully boxed.